# echo pre-defined names in main index

Tags: php

Pre-declared the following as i am making my site more stable than it is currently.

**mainconstants.php**

```
<?php
define("website_name", "Rs-Sanctuary ");
define("url", "http://Rs-Sanctuary.com/");
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
include('contants/mainconstants.php');?><br>
<title><?php echo ''.['website_name'].'' ?> - RSPS Toplist - Runescape private servers</title>
```

Why is it that my title bar says this

> "Array - RSPS Toplist - Runescape private servers"

and not

> "Rs-Sanctuary - RSPS Toplist - Runescape private servers"

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. You changed the code so that the error had been removed - please don't do that, as it makes your question impossible to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<title><?php echo website_name; ?> - RSPS Toplist - Runescape private servers</title>
```

You should use `[`and `]` on arrays

When using constants you use them with no [quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php)

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Still the same output but now its just " website_name"
http://i.imgur.com/6YmaWUc.png

Comment: You sure there are no quotes?

Comment: <?php
include('contants/mainconstants.php');
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="language" content="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title><?php echo ''.website_name.'' ?> - RSPS Toplist - Runescape private servers</title>

Comment: <?php echo ''.website_name.'' ?>   replace with <?php echo website_name; ?> You don`t need to concatenate empty string

Comment: That isn't working , check the main post i've edited the index, also the URL:  http://rs-sanctuary.com/

Comment: Thanks for this actually helped, also for future reference guys, make sure you have spelt the includes correctly! <br> :Sadface:
Thanks for the help after providing an answer.

Comment: :P happens, configure your IDE to avoid this, include paths

Comment: Dreamweaver CS3 , im very oldschool haha, thanks again.

Comment: Try netbeans or php storm because you have the autocomplete feature (don`t know if Dreamweaver has it...)

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 5.4 `[ ]` can be used to define an array, so you are attempting to echo the array `array('website_name')`, which can't done (so you get `Array`).

Remove the `[ ]` or put them in the quotes to have them echoed.

```
<title><?php echo '[' . website_name . ']' ?> - RSPS Toplist - Runescape private servers</title>
```

Comment: updated my index page

Answer (score 0):

Echo constant variable without `[` brace

```
Wrong: //your code
<title><?php echo ''.['website_name'].'' ?>

Correct :
<title><?php echo website_name; ?>
OR
<title><?php echo ''.website_name.'' ?>
```

Comment: Its still giving me nothing more than : http://i.imgur.com/6YmaWUc.png